# Accordion menu open and close

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an accordion style menu with 5 section, each of which has a submenu. Section can be opened and closed by clicking on them. The problem is that when a user clicks on a new section the previous section stays open. I am trying to figure out a way to get trigger a section to close automatically when the user  clicks on a different section so only the latest section they click on stays open. MY code is below.

Code uploaded to Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/brianmaddendesign/spacbe9y/

```js
(function() {
  var d = document,
    accordionToggles = d.querySelectorAll('.js-accordionTrigger'),
    setAria,
    setAccordionAria,
    switchAccordion,
    touchSupported = ('ontouchstart' in window),
    pointerSupported = ('pointerdown' in window);

  skipClickDelay = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.click();
  }

  setAriaAttr = function(el, ariaType, newProperty) {
    el.setAttribute(ariaType, newProperty);
  };
  setAccordionAria = function(el1, el2, expanded) {
    switch (expanded) {
      case "true":
        setAriaAttr(el1, 'aria-expanded', 'true');
        setAriaAttr(el2, 'aria-hidden', 'false');
        break;
      case "false":
        setAriaAttr(el1, 'aria-expanded', 'false');
        setAriaAttr(el2, 'aria-hidden', 'true');
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };
  //function
  switchAccordion = function(e) {
    console.log("triggered");
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisAnswer = e.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
    var thisQuestion = e.target;
    if (thisAnswer.classList.contains('is-collapsed')) {
      setAccordionAria(thisQuestion, thisAnswer, 'true');
    } else {
      setAccordionAria(thisQuestion, thisAnswer, 'false');
    }
    thisQuestion.classList.toggle('is-collapsed');
    thisQuestion.classList.toggle('is-expanded');
    thisAnswer.classList.toggle('is-collapsed');
    thisAnswer.classList.toggle('is-expanded');

    thisAnswer.classList.toggle('animateIn');
  };
  for (var i = 0, len = accordionToggles.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (touchSupported) {
      accordionToggles[i].addEventListener('touchstart', skipClickDelay, false);
    }
    if (pointerSupported) {
      accordionToggles[i].addEventListener('pointerdown', skipClickDelay, false);
    }
    accordionToggles[i].addEventListener('click', switchAccordion, false);
  }

})();
```

Comment: Could you provide your `css` and `html`?

Comment: can you please upload your html,JS,Css  code to fiddle

Comment: You assume that your menu items will be open sequentially?

Answer (score 0):

I added a little code to your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spacbe9y/3/). Hope this is what you're looking for.

```
var menuTitle = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-content'),
      menuCont = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-title'),
    i = 0;

while(i < menuTitle.length) {
    if(!e.target.classList.contains('is-expanded')) {
        menuTitle[i].classList.remove('is-expanded', 'animateIn');
        menuTitle[i].classList.add('is-collapsed');
        menuCont[i].classList.remove('is-expanded', 'is-collapsed');
    };
    i++;
};
```

When you click a menu item, it checks to see if any menu element is expanded and closes that element before running your code.